# dynamically update format string of logging module in python

Tags: python-3.x, logging

So, I am aware in python logging module, I can do the following to add extra keys

```py
logging.basicConfig(format='%(msg)s %(key)s')
logging.info("some message", extra={"key": "value"})
```

But now, I have a use case where I can pass in arbitrary number of key value pair to `extra` parameter and I want to log those keys. To achieve this I have to update the format every time. Is there a way to dynamically do this?

For example:

```py
# I start the logger with basic config 
logging.basicConfig(format="%(msg)s")

# then when logging I add some new extra keys
logging.info("sme message", extra={"new_key": value")
# how can I make that `new_key` appear in logs, by updating the formatter such that it 
# reads the new keys passed in
```